# Replace over 1M pandas values using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Now, I'm researching about STRING network

When I want to replace STRING protein to Entrez ID, I see that STRING data has over 1M pandas rows.(~11M rows)

So, I tried to replace STRING protein ID(like 9606.ENSP00000~~) to Entrez ID(integer).

All methods was very slow.

but when I use this code, the time elapsed < 5 min.

**is this code not problem?**

Here is the code.
`

```
def replace_string_id(self, data: pd.DataFrame, target_col: str, rename_dict: dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    tmp_list = []
    for target, tmp_df in data.groupby(target_col):
        if target in rename_dict.keys():
            tmp_df[target_col] = rename_dict[target]
            tmp_list.append(tmp_df)
        else:
            continue
    # merging

    return_df = pd.concat(tmp_list)
    return return_df
```

string_link_df is like:

```
    protein1    protein2    combined_score 
0   381 9606.ENSP00000379496    155
1   381 9606.ENSP00000314067    197
2   381 9606.ENSP00000263116    222
...
```

and replace_dict is like:

```
{'9606.ENSP00000263100': 1,
 '9606.ENSP00000323929': 2,
 '9606.ENSP00000443194': 9,
 '9606.ENSP00000286479': 10,
 '9606.ENSP00000376793': 12,
 '9606.ENSP00000450540': 12,
 '9606.ENSP00000232892': 13,
...
}

string_renamed = replace_string_id(string_link_df, 'protein2', replace_dict)
```

`

This code is more faster than other methods.

-- Edit 2023-06-023 KST --
Thanks for all who comments my question.

Here is my full data.

**string data:**
can download here: https://string-db.org/cgi/download?sessionId=bNSFUedQrsqe&species_text=Homo+sapiens

**link data file name:** 9606.protein.links.v11.5.txt.gz

**info data file name:** 9606.protein.info.v11.5.txt.gz

you can make info data to dict using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from pathlib import Path

def main(args):
    # read string alias data
    string_alias_df = pd.read_csv(args.string_alias_path, sep="\t", dtype={"alias": str}, compression="gzip")
    
    # set target source which have Entrez ID
    target_source_list = [
        "BLAST_KEGG_GENEID",
        "BLAST_UniProt_DR_GeneID",
        "Ensembl_HGNC_Entrez_Gene_ID",
        "Ensembl_HGNC_Entrez_Gene_ID(supplied_by_NCBI)",
        "Ensembl_HGNC_UniProt_ID(supplied_by_UniProt)_DR_GeneID",
        "Ensembl_UniProt_DR_GeneID"
    ]
    
    # make string alias to Entrez
    alias_df = []
    for string_id, string_id_df in tqdm(string_alias_df.groupby('#string_protein_id')):
        target_rows = string_id_df[string_id_df['source'].isin(target_source_list)]
        if len(target_rows):
            target_row = target_rows.iloc[0]
            tmp_series = pd.Series(
                data=[string_id, target_row['alias']],
                index=["STRING ID", "Entrez"]
            )
        else:
            tmp_series = pd.Series(
                data=[string_id, ""],
                index=["STRING ID", "Entrez"]
            )
        alias_df.append(tmp_series)

    alias_df = pd.DataFrame(alias_df)
    
    # Need to STRIP
    # alias_df['Entrez'] = alias_df['Entrez'].str.strip()
    
    # save
    alias_df.to_csv(
        args.string_alias_path.parent.joinpath("STRING_Entrez_mapping_table.tsv"), 
        sep="\t", 
        header=True, 
        index=False,
    )
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    ref_dir = Path(__file__).parent.parent.joinpath("references", "STRING")
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--string_alias_path", type=Path, default=ref_dir.joinpath("9606.protein.aliases.v11.5.txt.gz"))
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

**Original String data is like:**

```
protein1    protein2    combined_score
0   9606.ENSP00000000233    9606.ENSP00000379496    155
1   9606.ENSP00000000233    9606.ENSP00000314067    197
2   9606.ENSP00000000233    9606.ENSP00000263116    222
3   9606.ENSP00000000233    9606.ENSP00000361263    181
4   9606.ENSP00000000233    9606.ENSP00000409666    270
```

And I need all of this columns.

and I make two functions.

One is Simon David suggested:

```
def use_replace(string, target_col, replace_dict) -> None:
    data = string.copy()
    data = data.replace({target_col: replace_dict})
    pass
```

Other one is I suggested:

```
def replace_string_id(data: pd.DataFrame, target_col: str, rename_dict: dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    tmp_list = []
    for target, tmp_df in data.groupby(target_col):
        if target in rename_dict.keys():
            tmp_df[target_col] = rename_dict[target]
            tmp_list.append(tmp_df)
        else:
            continue

    return_df = pd.concat(tmp_list)
```

I tried to check execute time use_replace functions, but it takes over 1 min.

use_replace(string, "protein1", replace_dict)

And, replace_string_id functions execute time is:

```
%timeit replace_string_id(string, "protein1", replace_dict)
2.43 s ± 5.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, I asked this question.
Why pandas replace is slower than just use dictionary k,v in over 1M rows and want to know is this code(replace_string_id) has any other problems.

Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please explain better what you want to replace and to what. Is it by a dictionary you have prepared?

Comment: @MattDMO My question is that whether this code has any problem to replace the value.

Comment: @gtomer I want to more faster method to replace value in pandas using dictionary. Pandas.DataFrame.replace is very slow than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right and you are after replacing using a dict you can:

```
df.replace({"protein2": d})
```

where d is you dict, e.g.:

```
d = {'9606.ENSP00000263100': 1, '9606.ENSP00000323929': 2, '9606.ENSP00000443194': 9, '9606.ENSP00000286479': 10, '9606.ENSP00000376793': 12, '9606.ENSP00000450540': 12, '9606.ENSP00000232892': 13, ... }
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is general method to replace value.
But my data(e.g. STRING link data) has over 10M rows. this replace method is too slow.

Comment: Did you try the df.replace line I wrote above? It should be fairly fast

Comment: Of course I tried it, but it takes over 1 min

Comment: I don't think you will get any faster than that

Comment: I edited my question. see the updated version. 
My replace code just takes 2.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, an alternative for `.replace()` is using `.map()` in conjunction with `.fillna()`, which is a bit faster than `.replace()`. I've added a code example below which performs this operation on 12 million rows, using both approaches. In this simple experiment, the `.map()` approach is about 3 times faster than `.replace()`. **However, according to this analysis, both approaches should be fast enough for your dataset.** In case this code runs substantially slower with your dataset, I would recommend you to either "`chunk`" your data or omit any columns you don't need in the loading process, as described in this [pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html#).

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time

# Part 1: Generate DataFrame
factor = 3_000_000

data = {
    "protein1": [381, 381, 381, 381] * factor,
    "protein2": [
        '9606.ENSP00000263100', '9606.ENSP00000323929',
        '9606.ENSP00000443194', '9606.NOTFOUND'
        ] * factor,
    "combined_score": [155, 197, 222, 259] * factor
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mapping_dict = {'9606.ENSP00000263100': 1,
 '9606.ENSP00000323929': 2,
 '9606.ENSP00000443194': 9,
 '9606.ENSP00000286479': 10,
 '9606.ENSP00000376793': 12,
 '9606.ENSP00000450540': 12,
 '9606.ENSP00000232892': 13,
}

def use_replace(df, tar_col, mapping_dict):

    df = df.replace({tar_col: mapping_dict})

    return df

def use_map_fillna(df, tar_col, mapping_dict):

    df["_"] = df[tar_col].map(mapping_dict)
    df[tar_col] = df["_"].fillna(df[tar_col])
    df.drop(columns=["_"], inplace=True)

    return df

# Part 2: execute functions
# use_replace()
tic = time()
output_df = use_replace(df=df, tar_col='protein2', mapping_dict=mapping_dict)
toc = time()
print(f"seconds passed: {toc - tic}")
# seconds passed: 7.794971704483032
print(output_df.head(n=5).to_markdown(index=False))
# |   protein1 | protein2      |   combined_score |
# |-----------:|:--------------|-----------------:|
# |        381 | 1.0           |              155 |
# |        381 | 2.0           |              197 |
# |        381 | 9.0           |              222 |
# |        381 | 9606.NOTFOUND |              259 |
# |        381 | 1.0           |              155 |

# use_map_fillna()
tic = time()
output_df = use_map_fillna(df=df, tar_col='protein2', mapping_dict=mapping_dict)
toc = time()
print(f"seconds passed: {toc - tic}")
# seconds passed: 2.3541603088378906
print(output_df.head(n=5).to_markdown(index=False))
# |   protein1 | protein2      |   combined_score |
# |-----------:|:--------------|-----------------:|
# |        381 | 1.0           |              155 |
# |        381 | 2.0           |              197 |
# |        381 | 9.0           |              222 |
# |        381 | 9606.NOTFOUND |              259 |
# |        381 | 1.0           |              155 |
```